# Specified cast is not valid error when sql column is null or tinyint

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that's filled with data from the database. And one of the column is either int or null. Int the DataBase the column appear under the type TINYINT.

In my code i have a model that correspond with that table and i declared the particular attribute under a int type. i get it like that:

```
foreach(var attr in attributes)
{
   MyAttribute cat = new MyAttribute();
   cat.glot = attr.isNull("attrGlot") ? 0 : attr.Field<int>("attrGlot");
}
```

So basicly i'm checking if it's a null and assign 0 if not i take the int value.

This is an example of how i declared MyAttribute:

```
public class MyAttribute
{
  public int glot {get;set;}
}
```

But it says the specific cast is not valid. I also tried with int? but i want to get int so this column kinda messes me up. Is there a particular type inside c# that i can use when doing .Field or i have to do this differently?

If i declare my tinyInt as Byte i get an error "CAnnot cast DBNull.Value to type "System.Byte".

Comment: It seems your database value is `NULL`. What datatype is `attributes` of?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're using to connect to your database. What is the type of `attributes` and, subsequently, what's the type of `attr`? I may be wrong, but there shouldn't be any public methods in typical .NET libraries with names starting with a lower-case char, so `isNull` seems to point to some kind of custom type?

Comment: You literally *just* asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469252/specified-cast-is-not-valid-inside-when-doing-fieldint

Comment: `new MyAttribute;` - How does that even compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IsDBNull(), it checks for the presence of an object that says 'the value is NULL in the database', which is different from checking for a null value in C#/.NET.

You can then do it like this:

```
cat.glot = attr.IsDBNull("attrGlot") ? 0 : attr.Field<int>("attrGlot");
```

Or if that still causes problems, use this:

```
cat.glot = attr.IsDBNull("attrGlot") ? 0 : (attr.Field<int?>("attrGlot") ?? 0);
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check. The call to `GetValueOrDefault` ensures that the result is always the underlying type of the Nullable (in this case, `int`), and that 0 is used if there is no value.

Comment: Same thing, is there a way to get the field value no matter what type of the column? Cause i can't even inspect what's the value its trying to convert. the column has either null or an int.

Comment: Have you tried using IsDBNull() instead of IsNull? This could make quite a difference.

Comment: That helped actually. I've inspected the type it's actually Int16 and then i did what you suggested first time. .Field<Int16?>("attrGlot") ?? 0 and it works. Thanks man

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly so everything is in one place.